# Vscode react native not working debug in exponent

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

The problem is that if i try to debug in exponent with vscode using react-native-tools, my app is not loading in simulator and device.

[Screenshot of simulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5W0Y.png)

Details can be found here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1137

Let me know if you have some ideas. Thanks.

tried reinstalling vscode react native tools and updating expo, expo-cli, using ios 12 simulator and ios 13 simulator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here, just remove `https: false` in *settings.json*
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1137